# Declaration Merging in Script file vs in Module Results in Different Outcome

Tags: typescript, express-session

I am trying to add properties to `req.session` object from `express-session` via `SessionData` interface.

I am using declaration merging to do so, but i get some behavior which i don't understand.

I have done the following:

```
declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData{
    myProperty: myProperty_t
  }
}
```

What i don't understand is that this only works if the file is a module (i.e. has top level import/export) and not if it is a script file.

I would have thought it would be the other way around, since i would want this change to be global (which is essentially my understanding of scripts vs modules).

I have very limited Typescript experience and I cant seem to find (or maybe understand) any resources regarding this.

Can someone please explain the difference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module augmentation using script file(one without export/import at the top level) is treated as [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules), i.e kind of module augmentation which assume that there's no existing type definition so it's the only one and it override any existing module types. Ambient modules are how the [DefinitelyTypes](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types) are written.

If you want to augment existing module types then the augmentation file must be in module scope(with export/import at the top) to enable the actual augmentation(it assume there's existing module types or will not try to shadow/override the existing types)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is in need of an inline type decloration merging without creating additional files to import, here is my solution:

```js
app.post('foo', (req, res)=>{
    /**
     * @type {Express.Request["session"] & {myProperty?: myProperty_t}}
     */
    let sess = req.session
    //...
}
```

The downside is it needs to be done for every middleware separately, but hey, it does work.